# Inertia of a quadratic form

Tags: quadratic-forms

This is a study question.

Let $q(x)=\sum_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)^2$ be a quadratic form over $R^n$. Find the inertia of $q(x)$.

I have tried to expand the sum and represent $q(x)$ as a matrix, however I am left then with trying to calculate the determinant of a matrix of size $n\times n$.

What is the correct way to begin solving this problem? A hint would be great!

Comment: You say that quadratic form is over $R^n$, so why do you think that matrix is infinite?

Comment: That was the wrong choice of words, my apologies. I edited my statement.

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The result I have indicated you, more precisely the answer by RicLouRiv

$$Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{r < s} (x_r - x_s)^2$$

$$=(n-1)y_1^2+(n-2)y_2^2+\cdots + 1 \cdot y_{n-1}^2 + 0\cdot y_n^2$$

where

$$y_k := \sqrt{\frac{n}{n-k+1}}\left(x_k - \frac{x_{k+1}+\cdots+x_n}{n-k}\right)$$

can receive a nice statistical interpretation as the progressive knowledge on the global mean computed on known samples $x_n, x_{n-1}, ... x_{k+1}$ while new data $x_k$ upcomes (I am obliged to work backwards to preserve the notations as they are). See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021999188901830